# Where do questions requesting libraries and APIs belong?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have been marked several times on Stack Overflow for asking about libraries and APIs that would solve certain problems or do certain things;  where do such questions belong?

Answer (score 11):

Your questions may be suitable on the [**Software Recommendations**](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) beta site.

For more information see:

- **FAQ**: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- **FAQ**: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)
- **Meta**: [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Comment: Yes, but they have pretty strict guidelines, so please read their help center before posting to make sure your question is on topic.